Why changing column using loc doesn't change the dtype
I'm trying to alter some string columns to datetime, but when I use loc to select them, the dtype doesn't change. Using the base python slice works. Here's the example with both attempts:
1. Using loc
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['col1'] = ['2022-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2023-12-01']*3
df['col2'] = df['col1'].str.replace('..$', '03', regex=True)

df.loc[:, ['col1', 'col2']] = df.loc[:, ['col1', 'col2']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

df.info()

The output is:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 9 entries, 0 to 8
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   col1    9 non-null      object
 1   col2    9 non-null      object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 276.0+ bytes

2. Using base slice:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['col1'] = ['2022-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2023-12-01']*3
df['col2'] = df['col1'].str.replace('..$', '03', regex=True)

df[['col1', 'col2']] = df[['col1', 'col2']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

The output is:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 9 entries, 0 to 8
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------  --------------  -----         
 0   col1    9 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 1   col2    9 non-null      datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2)
memory usage: 276.0 bytes



That's normal, assigning to part of a column (which you do with :, even if the part is the whole) doesn't change the dtype.
